# Sessions in Asp.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

Can anybody please tell me how to handle sessions in asp.net MVC 4. I am aware about this Session variable and I know how to use it.

```
Session["login"] = true; //We can use it in controller to check the whether user logged in or not.
```

Above code snippet is enough to handle sessions on small web application. But, what if I have many controllers and actions and I am working on a large application, In this case I cant use session variable in each action.

Is there is any generic place where I can check my session variables or any other solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1st Way:

I used to write a Base Controller class and all other Controllers inherit from it that need to authenticated before access:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["User"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "LogOut", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            else
                filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            //base.Execute(filterContext.RequestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and inherit from Base Controller in the ones for which user must be logged in:

```
public class LeaveController : DefaultController
{

}
```

Another way is to write your own authorizaion attribute.

See [Filter and Attributes in asp.net mvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577776/Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC)

### 2nd Way:

Here is sample for custom filter attribute, create class which inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["someValueYouLookFor"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index"); // redirect to login action
        }
        else
        {
            // continue normal execution 
        }
    }
}
```

and put it on Controller or Action:

```
[SessionTimeout]
public ActionResult Index()
{


}
```

Comment: Thanks I understood what you tried to say. Let me check it

Comment: Ehsan, its redirecting to the login page but the issue is its redirecting many times and then I get this error on the browser

The webpage at http://localhost:2015/login has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: do not inherit your login controller from BaseController

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can use Authentication filter if you're using MVC 5.

for simplest way, you can have a baseController, and all other controller should inherit that controller, and in baseController you can override that OnActionExecuting event, to verify if session is there or not.

for ex.

```
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["login"]))
            {
                //Authenticated
            }
            else
            { 
                //Kick to login page
            }
        }
```

All other controller should inherit this baseController

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This way, before your action method start executing, it will be verified through baseController's OnActionExecuting event.

Comment: Its redirecting many times to the login page and then I get error on browser.

its redirecting to the login page but the issue is its redirecting many times and then I get this error on the browser The webpage at localhost:2015/login has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

And then my server get crash after this